# git blame on a line modified multiple times?

Tags: git, blame

if a line is modified back and forth between 2 versions several times,
git blame seems to show only the latest commits on that line.

would it be possible to let it show all commits on that line?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file. Its doable, and quite easy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git blame` can't do that itself (but see below for a workaround).

But [`git gui`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) has a blame mode that allows you to drill down into commits.

Invoke it with `git gui blame <filename>` once installed.

Answer (score 16):

I don't know about showing all commits on that line *at the same time*, but you can "drill" through each change to the line by using `git blame SHA~ -- filename`. With each iteration of the blame, just insert the next most "recent" SHA which modified that line.

Example: The first time you run `git blame foo.php` you see the line was modified by `f8e2e89a`, so then you exit out and run `git blame f8e2e89a~ -- foo.php`, git will then show you who modified the line before `f8e2e89a`. Rinse and repeat as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want with `git blame`, but you might get close with a word-diff algorithm or some other custom diff tool. In particular, you could show a line-by-line word diff in your log output like so:

```
# Show deletions delimited with [- -], and additions with {+ +}.
git log --patch --word-diff=plain
```

#### See Also

[Extract authorship information from git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922759/extract-authorship-information-from-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `git blame` is to show which commit most recently modified which lines in a particular file.  It does not have an option to show multiple versions of the same line.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately I was looking for something similar to the blame  button of perforce , which shows you all commits in history

Comment: You can kind of simulate that by doing `git blame HEAD~n -- filename` where `n` starts at 0 and increases.  This isn't interactive, but each time you increment the number you'll be looking further back in history.

Comment: hehehe . I used to do something similar in my svn days: perl -e 'for $v ( 0 .. $current_version ) { system(qq(svn diff -r).($v-1).qq( -r$v   mysource.java ) } '

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers already provided here, I created a script called `git-rblame` in my PATH with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

revision="HEAD"

while [ -n "${revision}" ]
do
    result=$(git blame "${revision}" "$@")
    revision="${result%% *}"
    if [[ "${revision}" != [a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9] ]]
    then
        revision=""
    else
        echo "${result}"
        revision="${revision}~"
    fi
done
```

Then I can call `git rblame -L xxx,yyy myfilename` and I'll get the full history for the file respective the content given. Given the fact that the line number might change, a meaningful regexp seems to work better.